# C++ & SFML Separating Axis Theorem

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I'm trying to implement collision detection in sfml using the separating axis theorem but my function to get the min translation vector (getMtv()) is always returning that there is a collision (MTV::IsValid()). I was following [a tutorial here](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/)

but I can't see where I went wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

typedef sf::Vector2f Vector2;
typedef sf::Vector2f Axis;
typedef sf::Vector2f Projection;
typedef std::vector<Axis> AxesVec;

class MTV
{
private:
    bool _valid;
    Axis _axis;
    float _overlap;

public:

    MTV(Axis axis, float overlap, bool valid)
    {
        _valid = valid;
        _overlap = overlap;
        _axis = axis;
    }

    bool IsValid() const
    {
        return _valid;
    }

};

Vector2 perpendicular(Vector2 v)
{
    return Vector2(v.y, -v.x);
}

float dot(Vector2 vec1, Vector2 vec2)
{
    return (vec1.x * vec2.x) + (vec1.y * vec2.y);
}

float magnitude(Vector2 v)
{
    return std::sqrt(dot(v,v));
}

class Polygon : public sf::ConvexShape
{
public:
    const AxesVec& GetAxes() const
    {
        return axes;
    }

    AxesVec axes;

void generateAxes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < getPointCount(); i++)
    {
        // get the current vertex
        Vector2 p1 = getPoint(i); //shape.vertices[i];
        // get the next vertex
        Vector2 p2 =  getPoint(i + 1 == getPointCount() ? 0 : i + 1);
        // subtract the two to get the edge vector
        Vector2 edge = p1 - p2;
        // get either perpendicular vector
        Vector2 normal = perpendicular(edge);
        // the perp method is just (x, y) => (-y, x) or (y, -x)
        axes.push_back(normal / magnitude(normal));
    }
};

float cross(Vector2 vec1, Vector2 vec2)
{
    return (vec1.x * vec2.y) - (vec1.y * vec2.x);
}

Vector2 project(Polygon p, Axis axis)
{
    float min = dot(axis, p.getPoint(0)); //axis.dot(shape.vertices[0]);
    float max = min;
    for (int i = 1; i < p.getPointCount(); i++)
    {
        // NOTE: the axis must be normalized to get accurate projections
        float prj = dot(axis, p.getPoint(i));//axis.dot(shape.vertices[i]);
        if (prj < min)
        {
            min = prj;
        }
        else if (prj > max)
        {
            max = prj;
        }
    }
    //Projection proj = new Projection(min, max);
    return Projection(min, max);
}

class Collison
{
private:
    Vector2 mtv;
    Polygon a;
    Polygon b;
};

bool overlap(Projection a, Projection b)
{
    // x = min & y = max
    return !(a.x > b.y || a.x > b.y);
}

float getOverlap(Projection a, Projection b)
{
    // x = min & y = max
    return (a.y < b.y) ? a.y - b.x : b.y - a.x;
}

MTV getMtv(Polygon a, Polygon b)
{
    float overlapMax = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();// really large value;
    float Overlap;

    Axis smallest;// = null;
    AxesVec axesA = a.GetAxes();
    AxesVec axesB = b.GetAxes();

    // loop over the axes1
    for (auto&& axis : axesA) //for (int i = 0; i < axes1.length; i++)
    {
        //Axis axis = axes1[i];
        // project both shapes onto the axis
        Projection pA = project(a, axis);
        Projection pB = project(b, axis);
        // do the projections overlap?
        if (!overlap(pA, pB)) //(!p1.overlap(p2))
        {
            // then we can guarantee that the shapes do not overlap
            return MTV(smallest, 0, false);
        }
        else
        {
            // get the overlap
            float o = getOverlap(pA, pB); //p1.getOverlap(p2);
            // check for minimum
            if (o < overlapMax)
            {
                // then set this one as the smallest
                Overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto&& axis : axesB) //for (int i = 0; i < axes1.length; i++)
    {
        //Axis axis = axes1[i];
        // project both shapes onto the axis
        Projection pA = project(a, axis);
        Projection pB = project(b, axis);
        // do the projections overlap?
        if (!overlap(pA, pB)) //(!p1.overlap(p2))
        {
            // then we can guarantee that the shapes do not overlap
            return MTV(smallest, 0, false);
        }
        else
        {
            // get the overlap
            double o = getOverlap(pA, pB); //p1.getOverlap(p2);
            // check for minimum
            if (o < overlapMax)
            {
                // then set this one as the smallest
                Overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;
            }
        }
    }

    //MTV mtv = new MTV(smallest, overlap);
    // if we get here then we know that every axis had overlap on it
    // so we can guarantee an intersection
    return MTV(smallest, Overlap, true);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Polygon polygon;
    polygon.setPointCount(3);
    polygon.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(500, 100));
    polygon.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(250, 500));
    polygon.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(750, 500));
    polygon.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    polygon.generateAxes();

    Polygon polygon2;
    polygon2.setPointCount(3);
    polygon2.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(100, 0));
    polygon2.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(50, 150));
    polygon2.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(150, 150));
    polygon2.generateAxes();

    //polygon2.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(100, 0));
    //polygon2.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(500, 150));
    //polygon2.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(250, 150));

    polygon2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        window.draw(polygon);
        window.draw(polygon2);
        std::cout << getMtv(polygon, polygon2).IsValid() << std::endl;

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `valid`'s value ever changed?

Comment: I implemented SAT using that tutorial with SFMl couple of months ago. I will take a closer look once I get home, but what I see now is that you don't check for containment. http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/#sat-contain

Comment: I havent implemented containment yet but my polygon is only partially inside the other. Also valid should be set to false in mtv's constructor when there is no overlap.

Comment: Whe do you call `void generateAxes()`?

Comment: yes I forgit to call generateAxes nice catch. However, it's still  behaving the same. I've updated the code in the post

Comment: check your `overlap` function, it does not seem right.

Comment: can you be more specific? I don't see whats wrong with overlap.

Comment: @GregWilliamson  `overlap({11,-10}, {-14, -9})` returns false.